# Axios ignores the replay

Tags: javascript, axios, response

I have the following code:

```
request(options).then( ( res ) => {
    if(res.data.jobStatus === "ACTIVE"){
        this.setState({
            jobId: res.data.jobId,
        })
        alert("Calculation started: " +  this.state.activeCalcDates );    
    }
})
```

For what I understand, `.then()` should wait for axios `function ( request )`
to be actually complete before running `.then()`

However my code will just blow through and `jobId` will stay `undefined`, breaking logic after the query.

I know every response from server does indeed included `res.data.jobStatus === "ACTIVE"`
but js will only rarely acknowledge this, and mostly just ignore `jobStatus` and keep client hanging with last `PASSIVE` status.

```
2 < 202
2 < Content-Type: application/json
{
  "status" : "BUSY",
  "currentJob" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "jobId" : "xxxx-yyyy-zzzz",
    "jobStatus" : "ACTIVE"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `res.data.jobStatus` with `res.data.currentJob.jobStatus`. And also `res.data.jobId` with `res.data.currentJob.jobId`.